# What do you call these people on the street?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

What is the name for the people on the street who often times work for a non-profit organization and usually are soliciting donations (but maybe doing other things such as collecting signatures for a petition, or just spreading information)?

You can usually tell who they are because they're wearing a uniform and holding clipboards and approaching strangers who walk by. I was just accosted by one and would like to know how to refer to them so I can relay the story to other people.

Comment: One less rant on Facebook. A close vote well used.

Comment: Excellent question.  If it were by phone, it would be telephone solicitation.  I really don't know what to call these people, but I would like to know.  They're not necessarily volunteers.

Comment: @tchrist please confirm why this is not a good fit for this site? Considering there are well used tags for this type of questions it is unclear.

Comment: @aparente001 agreed, the first word that popped into my mind was volunteer but this may be inaccurate as 1) their job requires them to perform this function 2) they may be paid for this work. Hence, not a volunteer.

Comment: In the UK at least, these people are often referred to as "chuggers", which is a portmanteau of "charity muggers": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_fundraising

Comment: You are asking what is the generic name of the profession of people doing "door-to-door work/delivery/services". It is very interesting. I wonder if there such a name. There are door-to-door-sales-persons/people, delivery-boys, volunteers, street-hawkers (selling vegetables door to door), courrier-service-boys, news-paper-boys, lunch-delivery-boys, charity-collectors.

Answer (score 6):

In the UK at least, these people are often referred to as "chuggers", which is a portmanteau of "charity muggers": en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Street_fundraising

Answer (score 1):

For use in the U.S., I will make something up, based on the comment by @blackpen.

*Political hawkers*

Also, I suppose one could use the existing word

*Leafletters*

(from the verb *to leaflet*)

Answer (score 1):

Generically, these are 'canvassers'. They 'canvas', and the results are a 'canvas':

> *v.tr*
>   ....
>   **2. a.** To go through (a region) or go to (persons) to solicit votes or orders.
>   *v.intr*
>   ....
>   **2.** To solicit voters, orders, or opinions.
>   *n.*
>   ....
>   **2.** A solicitation of votes or orders.
>
> ---
>
> [From obsolete `canvass`, *to toss in a canvas sheet as punishment*, from *canvas*.]
>
> ---
>
> **can′vass·er** *n.*

(*American Heritage® Dictionary of the English Language*, Fifth Edition. S.v. "canvasser." Retrieved September 21 2016 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/canvasser.)